# How to infer parameter type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

How infer parameter type?

I want to implement a state management library similar to redux, and I have trouble defining types.
The prototype is as follows:

```
interface IModel<S, A> {
  state: S
  action: IActions<S, A>
}

type IActions<S, A> =  {
  [K in keyof A]: (state: S, payload: ???) => void // `???` How should it be defined here
}

class Model<T,A> implements IModel<T,A>{
  //...
}

// examples

const model=new Model({
  state:{name:"foo"},
  action:{
    setName:(state,name: string)=>{
      //...
    },
    fetchAccount:(state,payload: {
      id: number,
      locked: boolean,
      ...
})=>{
      //...
    }
  }
})

//
let state={name:''}
model.action.setName(state,'bar') // ok
model.action.setName(state,123)   // error
```

Comment: TypeScript is not C#, so please don't use `I` as a type-name prefix for interfaces.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you don't use [the official TypeScript bindings for Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit)? Have you read https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript ?

Comment: This Model and IModel are only used for the problem description here to make it more intuitive. The actual code does not have the definition of the IModel interface at all. It is the same as redux but its representation
 and implementation are different. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have strict type checking in the specific case where your method names match your state property names, you can use [template literal types and mapped type `as` clauses](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336). This requires Typescript 4.1 or newer.

The general gist is to take the state keys (in this case `name`), and map them to corresponding method names (`setName`) with the correct signatures (`(state: State, value: string) => void`).

```
type Actions<State> = {
  [K in keyof State & string as `set${Capitalize<K>}`]: (state: State, value: State[K]) => void;
}

type Model<State> = {
  state: State;
  actions: Actions<State>;
}

const model: Model<{ name: string }> = {
  state: {
    name: 'foo',
  },
  actions: {
    setName(state, value) {
      state.name = value;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: In case you couldn't tell, I got [nerd sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) by this question pretty hard.

Comment: Your approach is very close, but action is not a fixed method at the beginning of set. The method name and parameters are not restricted, and the parameters are not necessarily matched with state. I will modify the above example again to make it clearer

Comment: @jun You can't have type safety for arbitrary actions. In the simplest case, imagine a state where one field is a string and another one is a number, there is no way to infer which you should be passing to an arbitrarily named action.

Comment: This is the problem at the moment, so I just post for help